# What does “stunt babies” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I’m watching a documentary, and a sentence confuses me.

> Births in royal families were always packed out, it was an honour, and also people there to make sure that the right baby came and was kept. So no ***stunt babies*** were brought in.

It would be appreciated if you could help me understand this phase. Thanks!

Comment: Without further context to clarify, it's hard to be completely sure. Apparently, as well as stuntmen and stuntwomen, there are stunt babies.

Comment: Thanks! With this comment I think I’ve understood it, I think it was just trying to tell us that in this way no “fake” babies were to be the future heir.

Comment: It makes sense. Bringing in body doubles would enable one to keep the true heirs safe, but would give a greater risk of identity mix-up / fraud.

Comment: I guess the purpose of a 'stunt baby' is to make sure the 'real baby' is safe. E.g. displaying a fake stunt baby in public instead of the 'real baby'. It seems out of respect to the people present ('packed out' event, an honour) in this case no stunt babies were used.

Comment: 'Stunt' seems wrong in this context unless said baby is to be hurled around the place. 'Body double' would be (one sincerely hopes) more accurate.

Comment: @NigelJ I think so, I also doubt it. By the way, “to be hurled around” is really funny (lovely) to imagine, hahahahaha! : )

Comment: @Benny No babies were harmed in the comments section of this question.

Comment: @NigelJ Of course not, I just found it quite humorous, and I did laugh : ) Thanks for you nice comments!

Comment: James Edward Stuart, the son of King James II by his second wife, was famously suspected of being an impostor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Francis_Edward_Stuart .  However 'stunt baby' seems a rather odd expression.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks, it’s very kind of you to give such a really nice comment!

Comment: "Stunt baby" sounds innovative and perhaps disrespectful but so what? Any detailed reading of history should show a huge part of being royal in the first place is securing the succession.

If you'll excuse the pun, history is littered with infertile kings or barren queens borrowing - prolly buying - other people's babies to give provide a total heir.

Also as others have pointed out, a substituted - for which, read "stunt" - baby could of course serve as a decoy to protect the real heir from assassins.